# Programmatically selecting options in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, prototypejs

I have a little script that generates a select field and selects the appropriate option when it's generated. It looks a bit like this:

```
options.each(function (option) {
    var optionString = "<option id='" + option.id + "' value='" + option.value + "'>" + option.text + "</option>";
    $('selectField').insert(optionString);
    if(option.selected) {
        toBeSelected = option.id;
    }
});
$(toBeSelected).setAttribute('selected','selected');
```

Now the above script works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE it will always select the last element in the list. so say I was generating a list of options `['a','b','c','d']`, 'd' would always be selected.

Does anybody have an idea what could be causing this?

UPDATE:
Okay, I found a solution to this, and it involved replacing the 'insert' with generating the option nodes manually, a bit like the following:

```
var newOption = document.createElement('option');
newOption.setAttribute('value',option.value);
newOption.innerHTML = option.text;
if(option.selected) {
    newOption.selected = true;
}

$('selectField').appendChild(newOption);
```

I'm guessing the issue lied with how the prototype `insert()` works, although I'm just glad the problem is solved.

I'll reformat this as an answer once the 8 hours are up to answer my own question.

Thankyou all for your input in this

Comment: What is the value of option.selected?

Comment: it's a bool, so either `true` or `false`

Comment: I'd suggest alerting every option.selected in IE to see what it gets. Also I'd replace the if statement with option.selected === true

Comment: @mplungjan He is using prototype library, not jQuery.

Comment: as I made some tests i get my desired option selected in Internet explorer 8, can you give a more detailed info? What prototype do you use? An example with your array?

Comment: I've put an alert in the if statement, and I'm certain `toBeSelected` is being set with the right value. in prototype the `$()` selector only selects ids, so doesn't require a `#`. This would only be required if I were using the `$$()` selector, which works much more like the jQuery Sizzle selector.

Comment: The version of prototype I'm using is bundled with Magento, and I believe it is version 1.6.0.3. It essentially generates the select field in a hidden div which is then displayed in a lightbox using the fancyzoom library. Do you think it could be a conflict with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution to this, and it involved replacing the 'insert' with generating the option nodes manually, a bit like the following:

```
var newOption = document.createElement('option');
newOption.setAttribute('value',option.value);
newOption.innerHTML = option.text;
if(option.selected) {
    newOption.selected = true;
}

$('selectField').appendChild(newOption);
```

I'm guessing the issue lied with how the prototype insert() works, although I'm just glad the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

```
var options = new Array();

options.push({id:1,value:'one',text:'text1',selected:false});
options.push({id:2,value:'two',text:'text2',selected:true});
options.push({id:3,value:'three',text:'text3',selected:false});
options.push({id:4,value:'four',text:'text4',selected:false});

var toBeSelected;
options.each(function(option) {
    var optionString = "<option id='" + option.id + "' value='" + option.value + "'>" + option.text + "</option>";
    $('selectField').insert(optionString);
    if (option.selected == true)
    {
        toBeSelected = option.id+""; // +"" because have to be a string
    }
});

$(toBeSelected).selected = true;
```

Comment: I've tried this, and still get the same result. I've put an alert in the if statement, and am certain `toBeSelected` is being set correctly.